# Validar Conexión a Internet - ¿Estoy realmente conectado a internet?

Tags: php

he venido con esta consulta hace unos días.
He estado buscando como validar la conexión a internet, y si tengo acceso a esta.
Hasta ahora he dado con el siguiente código: (Lo dejo al final) 
Este código básicamente funciona, pero he visto en otros lados que usan otros métodos diferentes para la misma solución. 
 Mi pregunta sería la siguiente: ¿Está realmente validando la conexión a internet?
 Que quiero decir con esto? 
Si estoy conectado a internet, digamos, a través de una red privada, y esta red no tiene conexión, el método esta validando mi conectividad a la red, o al mismo internet?
 Es necesario agregar a este método alguna otra validación?

```
switch (connection_status())
{
case CONNECTION_NORMAL:
  $msg = 'Estas conectado a Internet.';
  break;
case CONNECTION_ABORTED:
  $msg = 'No hay conexión a Internet';
  break;
case CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:
  $msg = 'Tiempo de espera agotado';
  break;
case (CONNECTION_ABORTED & CONNECTION_TIMEOUT):
  $msg = 'Tiempo de espera agotado, conexion abortada';
  break;
default:
  $msg = 'Indefinido';
  break;
}
//display connection status
echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la intención es saber si hay conexión a internet realmente, entendiendo por conexión que se pueda navegar, tienes sí  o sí que hacer una solicitud a algún dominio y verificar si ha sido posible dicha solicitud.

Un caso típico donde podría parecer que hay internet es que tengas conexión wifi a un router, pero que éste no tenga acceso a internet, porque la red está caída en ese momento o simplemente porque el router no está conectado a la línea telefónica, debido a que el gato o el perro anduvieron jugando por esa zona :)

Un script simple para verificar la conexión podría ser este:

```
function hasConnection(){
    exec("ping -c 1 google.com", $output, $result);
    return ($result===0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Esta función te devolverá `TRUE` solamente cuando haya conexión efectiva (el `ping` ha funcionado).

### Edición

@Elenasys tiene razón sobre las limitaciones de `ping`, por lo que en ciertos casos podría no ser óptimo para verificar si efectivamente hay conexión. Tampoco estoy seguro de que `fsockopen()` lo sea.

Según [esta respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/312936) el modo  más seguro de saber si un servicio está disponible, es haciendo una petición a ese servicio. Una forma simple y eficaz de hacerlo sería con `cURL`.

```
function hasConnection() {  
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
    curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Exacto a ese punto iba, mismo caso encontré donde mencionaban que tampoco era fiable obtener un ping a X página, ya que si la página está caida, te fallará la consulta cierto ?? De todos modos, dificilmente se caería google.com o example.com

Comment: @Excorpion si Google está caída, te dirá que no hay conexión. Pero si Google se cae, sería la catástrofe, casi el fin del mundo. Lo cierto es que nada es 100% en el mundo de la informática.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma usando `fsockopen()` tratando realizar la conexión a un sitio web :

```
function is_connected()
{
    $connected = @fsockopen("es.stackoverflow.com", 80); 
    if ($connected){
        $is_conn = true; //Conectado
        fclose($connected);
    }else{
        $is_conn = false; //No conectado
    }
    
    return $is_conn;

}


$conectado = is_connected();

print("Esta conectado : $conectado ");
```

Revisa:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860365/determine-in-php-script-if-connected-to-internet

Comment: Esto no es lo mismo que puso Cedaño antes ?? Que diferencia tiene usar sockets ?

Comment: Hola Excorpion, acabo de ver, esto abre una conexión a internet y comprueba si puede alcanzar el host remoto y lo  que agrega A. Cedaño llama externamente la utileria ping https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping yo prefiero usar el método que expongo, ya que si no tuvieras configurado TCP/IP en tu equipo pues no podría llamar ping :(

Comment: Básicamente es lo mismo, pero mejor ??

Comment: Es un punto de vista personal, no soy experto pero en este caso al consultar el host al cual tratas de acceder para probar la conexión el cual puede por alguna razón estar "abajo", personalmente no le agregaría también depender además de ping.

Comment: Igual, que si tomo los 3 métodos, imposible que los 3 juntos me fallen jajaj

Comment: Tienes razón sobre las limitaciones de hacer ping. Pero no estoy seguro que el uso de `fsockopen()` escape a ciertas limitaciones. Según [esta respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/312936) la forma más segura de verificar un recurso sería enviando una petición al mismo. He agregado otra posibilidad en la respuesta usando `cURL`.

Comment: @Excorpion haha!, bueno acabo de ver lo que dice A. Cedano, aún así nada es 100% seguro.